# Struggling to connect to MSSQL in PHP, Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect()

Tags: php, sqlsrv

Good Afternoon, I am trying to connect to a MSSQL database.

I am using:

```
PHP version 8.2.4
and using Xammp
```

The code I am using is:

```
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionOptions);
```

But it gives me the error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect()

Any ideas please?

In my php.ini file I have done:

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_82_ts_x64.dll
```

And in phpinfo() it shows various things about PDO, for example:

```
PDO Drivers show: sqlsrv
pdo_sqlsrv shows: ExtensionVer  5.11.0-beta1+16628
```

Comment: There are two different drivers for SQL Server, the "old" native one and the "new" PDO one. You've installed the PDO driver, so you need to use the new [PDO-style](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) code to connect. Your code here is the old style.